# use same matrix multiple times

Tags: matrices

Hello I've a matrix that I want to use multiple times in a file without having to rewrite it over and again. Is there a way to define a matrix 'object' and use it as an when I need it ?

Here is a minimal example of what I want to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\use{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% define the matrix 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \ast       & \ast  & 0      & \ast \\
    \ast       & \ast  & \ast   & 0 \\
     0         & \ast  & \ast   & \ast \\
    \ast       & 0     &\ast    &  \ast 
\end{pmatrix}
% end of matrix definition

\begin{equation} \label{eq:mat1}
% use the above defined matrix
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In general it will be good to know if there's a general method to apply such 'object' definition and use them to all kind of objects like figures, tikzpictures, etc multiple times as and when needed in the document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual method is to define macro via `\newcommand`.

For a `tikzpicture` you can use a similar technique or use `\pic` (example below is directly from the documentation Section 18).

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyMatrix}{%
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \ast       & \ast  & 0      & \ast \\
        \ast       & \ast  & \ast   & 0 \\
         0         & \ast  & \ast   & \ast \\
        \ast       & 0     &\ast    &  \ast 
    \end{pmatrix}}
% end of matrix definition


\tikzset{ seagull/.pic={
    \draw (-3mm,0) to [bend left] (0,0) to [bend left] (3mm,0);
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:mat1}
    \MyMatrix% use the above defined matrix
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [fill=blue!20, ultra thick] (1,1)
-- (2,2) pic {seagull} -- (3,2) pic {seagull} -- (3,1) pic [rotate=30] {seagull} -- (2,1) pic [red] {seagull};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```